# JUnit. assertEquals(Array.toString(), output.toString())

Tags: java, junit

How can I test it? I have to test show function. showMatrix() is a simple output array. How can I compare them?

```java
double[][] array = {{2, 3, 7},
                    {1, -5, 2},
                    {3, -1, 9}};
double[][] expected = {{2, 3, 7},
                       {1, -5, 2},
                       {3, -1, 9}};
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(stream);
PrintStream originalOutputStream = System.out;
System.setOut(out);
matrix.showMatrix(array);
System.setOut(originalOutputStream);
assertEquals(Arrays.toString(expected), stream.toString());
```

Comment: Please reword the question so that it's clear what are you asking.

Comment: Have you tried: `Assert.assertArrayEquals` ?

Comment: the posted code is confused looking, it's hard to tell what you want. calling toString on a stream seems like a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Assert.assertArrayEquals` method will work just fine.

Do not serialize the expected array, make sure your actual value is a 2D array (matrix), by the time you compare it to the original.

Your main issue seems to be converting back into a 2D array. You need to fix that.

```java
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;

public class MainTest {
    @Test
    public void testCompare() {
        double[][] actual = {
            { 2,  3, 7 },
            { 1, -5, 2 },
            { 3, -1, 9 }
        };

        double[][] expected = {
            { 2,  3, 7 },
            { 1, -5, 2 },
            { 3, -1, 9 }
        };

        assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```